# Async Sinatra failing with parameters in path

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eventmachine

I have an async_sinatra application that uses eventmachine in the following way:

```
aget '/test' do
    EM.defer { body 'test: ' + params[:foo] }
end
```

When I request the url as `/test?foo=bar` it yields `test: bar`, however when I declare the path as `aget '/test/:foo' do` and attempt to use `params[:foo]` the request never returns.

Why can't I use in-url parameters in async_sinatra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but you need to declare your route like this:

```
aget '/test/:foo' do
```

More info on this here:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes

(search for 'Route parameters')

Comment: I did declare the route as `aget '/test/:foo' do`, it's in the question. However, i did forget the quotes in the question...

Comment: oh sorry, missed that, did you try doing `/test/:foo do |foo|` and using just plain `foo` on the code block?

Comment: That worked. I wonder why it had such a problem with `params[:foo]`?

Comment: Where is the async sinatra source? maybe we can peek and see what's wrong there

Comment: It's on [GitHub](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra/). I looked it over quickly and nothing jumped out at me.